# PHP string replace the first and last occurance

Tags: php, html

I am trying to replace the occurrence of `li` tag with `a` tag but I also replace the other `li`s used in the string.

for example I have this:

```
<li id="item" class="list-item" href="#">Item</li>
```

but I want to replace the `li` tags without the `list-item` class name replaced.

if I do :

```
$f = array( '><a', 'li' );
$r = array( '', 'a' );
// output the menu
echo str_replace( $f, $r, $menu );
```

then the class name `list-item` becomes `ast-item` where `li` is replaced with `a`.

How can I just replace the li tag and not all the instance of li?

Comment: `preg_replace('/\bli\b/', 'a', $menu);`

Comment: @colburton your regex won't work in following example `<li>aa li</li>`

Comment: @Farnabaz: I know. It was a hint not an answer.

Comment: HTML/XML parsers are done for this.

Comment: This works https://3v4l.org/nIYK0 I think...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$input_lines = '<li id="item" class="list-item" href="#">Item</li>';
preg_replace("/\<(\/?)li([^\>]*)\>/", "<$1a$2>", $input_lines);
```

Comment: the thing is that I want to use this in wordpress menu and using this, I get this menu structure: https://pastebin.com/raw/Eu38YqmL which is not what I want

Comment: @user8265631 you want to convert menu `li` to anchor tag? you can't wrap `a` tag around another `a` tag, it's wrong.

Comment: I want to remove ul and li and just have <a id="" class=""> tag.

Comment: @user8265631 have you looked at any of the other answers or is this answer the only one you are interested in?

Answer (score 1):

You could try making your search params a bit more accurate to avoid that problem. Example:

```
$menu = "<li id=\"item\" class=\"list-item\" href=\"#\">Item</li>";
$f = array( '<li', '</li>' );
$r = array( '<a', '</a>' );
// output the menu
$x = str_replace( $f, $r, $menu );
```

Generally speaking, you should avoid parsing HTML with Regexs.

Comment: I agree with not using regex. Especially when you don't need to. And with static strings it's just a waste to use regex. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$string = '<li id="item" class="list-item" href="#">Item</li>';    
$string = preg_replace("/<li\s(.+?)>(.+?)<\/li>/is", "<a $1>$2</a>", $string);    
echo($string);
```

Comment: You forget `$1` inside the `<a>` tag : `"<a $1>$2</a>"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do exactly as the question states. **First and last li**
Then you can use strpos to find the first.
And use strrpos to find the last.

This is more a demonstration of the exact answer to the question rather than a good way.
As I linked to in the comments above str_replace is better.

```
$s = '<url id="item" class="list-item" href="#">Item</url>';
$find = "url";
$lenght = strlen($find);
$pos1 = strpos($s, $find);
$pos2 = strrpos($s, $find);

Echo substr($s,0,$pos1) . "a" . Substr($s,$pos1+$lenght,$pos2-$lenght-1) . "a" . Substr($s,$pos2+$lenght);
```

Note that I add or subtract from position depending on if I want to keep or delete the words.
https://3v4l.org/J1Na0

Updated with a more universal solution.

Comment: the thing is that I want to use this for wordpress menus and it does not work. so I want to replace url and li with just <a> tag

Comment: @user8264631 in the question you wrote `li` tag. Is it url now too? Update your question with a complete question!

Comment: @user8264631 try it now